# How to prevent a SQLAlchemy collection containing duplicates

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

This question concerns the values contained in the python collections, rather than in the database itself.

If I have a standard recursive many-to-one relationship:

```py
class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person'
    children = relationship(
        "Person",
        cascade="all, delete-orphan",
        backref=backref("parent", remote_side="Person.id"),
    )
```

and create a parent and child, then *re-add* the child to the parent, I get unexpected behaviour:

```py
>>> parent = Person()
>>> child = Person(parent=parent)
>>> session.add(parent, child)
>>> session.flush()
>>> child.parent = parent
>>> parent.children.append(child)
>>> len(parent.children)
2  # expected 1
>>> child.parent = None
>>> len(parent.children)
1  # expected 0
```

What is the best way to achieve the expected behaviour, where the `append` does nothing because the object is already in the collection? Because the relationship is recursive I don't really want to eager-load children, so if solutions can behave well when the `children` relationship is not loaded, that would be a big advantage - this is why I'm not keen on simply doing

```py
if child not in parent.children:
    parent.children.append(child)
```

but maybe this, and the attendant extra loads, are all that is really possible?

Comment: So you want to be sure that you aren’t appending a duplicate child but you don’t want to eager load the relationship?

Comment: @SuperShoot yep!